# How to view CakePHP AROs and ACOs and connections without using the shell?

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I need to view the ACOs and AROs from Cake PHP's ACL functionality.  The end result will have users with the highest access being able to modify the permissions of users with lower access - so I cannot use the shell to view ACL data, since I will need to have it displayed through code to the end user.

What is the best way to go about this?  I realise I could use SQL statements to extract the data from the tables directly and then display it, but ideally an inbuilt Cake PHP method to do this would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in GUI for ACL. There are a few plugins that facilitate these functionalities. The best this to do would be to look in GitHub and try a few options. You might want to start with https://github.com/FMCorz/AclManager

Comment: Thanks, I've got that working and it does exactly what I want. Do you have any ideas how it might be edited to allow for 2 levels of permissions for the plugin (i.e. admins can change the permissions for every user but managers can only change the permissions of basic users)?

Comment: sorry, I myself, have never used it